# sql to find certain ids and fillins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm needing to pull 3 rows from a table for a featured section on my site. I first retrieve a list of 3 items that are sold the most from an orders table. Then I need to check to see if there are any left. If so, pull their details from the inventory table. The problem is, I always need 3. If there are not 3 items from the orders table that are still in stock, i need enough to make 3, selected from random. How can I set `WHERE id IN (1, 2)` and then still pull 1 random record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a UNION to join the records `WHERE id IN (1, 2)` and then the second query is your random record.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id IN (1, 2)

UNION

SELECT Top 1 *
FROM table
```

If you provide more details about your query, then I can provide a more detailed answer.

Edit:
Based on your comment you should be able to do something this like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM list_cards 
WHERE card_id IN (1, 2) AND qty > 0

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM list_cards 
WHERE qty > 0
```

If you want to be sure you always get 3 results:

```
SELECT TOP 3 C.*
FROM
(
    SELECT C.*, '1' as Priority
    FROM list_cards C
    WHERE C.card_id IN (1, 2) AND qty > 0

    UNION

    SELECT C.*, '2' as Priority
    FROM list_cards C
    WHERE qty > 0
) C
ORDER BY C.Priority
```

Comment: well, i'm using cakephp and right now it's not showing my exactly what my query is. But I imagine it would look like `SELECT * FROM list_cards WHERE card_id IN (1, 2) AND qty > 0`

Comment: what happens if card_id 2 has a qty of 0? then i'll only get 2 results?

Comment: @LordZardeck edited answer to make sure you always get 3 records.  Added a field called priority so you can order by that field making sure you always the records from your first query.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `UNION` and another `SELECT`, with `LIMIT 1`?

Answer (score 3):

A hack like this where you select dummy data perhaps?

```
SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM
(
   SELECT * from table WHERE id IN (1,2)
   UNION 
   SELECT 0;
   UNION
   SELECT 0;
   UNION 
   SELECT 0;
)
ORDER BY [whatever field]
```